# JFace adapt TableViewerColumn

Tags: jface, tableviewer

I would like to compute the width for each TableViewerColumn so that it fits the content best. Is there any "best practice" way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're after ...

```
TableViewerColumn col = ...;
col.getColumn().pack();
```